# div resizes when border is removed

Tags: css, border, margin

I started having this problem lately where the div would be resized after i remove a border.

Notice this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rALvd/1/

If you remove the black border the red div no longer has a margin of 50px at the top and bottom but appears to have a lot bigger space at the bottom.

When you add border the red div goes back to having the correct margins.

Here is code:

```
<div id="main_contact">
<div id="contact_contain">
    <div id="contact_form">
    </div>
</div>
</div>

#main_contact {
width: 100%;
height: 450px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#contact_contain {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 350px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: url(homepage/contact.png) center center no-repeat;
margin-top: 50px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the normal behaviour of the box model. If you don't want the sizing to change, I suggest you change the border colour to match the adjacent area so it is not visible.

Comment: I have been using border: 1px solid transparent. I didn't know if this was best practice or not.

Comment: This behavior is called [margin collapsing](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins). There are some other ways to prevent it, e.g. by setting `display: table` or `overflow: auto` to the outer div (which makes it establish [new block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)). And you can also use padding of the outer div instead of the margin of the inner — paddings never collapse.